# Subsetting multi-index Pandas with label and boolean combination

Tags: python, pandas

Given a multi-index dataframe, how do I select all rows pertaining to one label of the index and that have a certain value in a column?

Here's an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['xy1','xy2','xy3'], ['1','2','3','4','5']], names=['Tag', 'Page'])
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,4,5,1,1,61,4,51,1,1,4,5,1], index, columns=['Value'])
df
```

from it I would like to select all rows with label *xy1* that in column *Value* have a 1. Hence, producing this:

```
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1','2','3']], names=['Page'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1], index2, columns=['Value'])
df2
```

How can I achieve this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and remove first level by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Tag == 'xy1' & Value == 1").reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Or first select by first level with [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and then filter by `Value` column:

```
df1 = df.xs('xy1').query("Value == 1")
print (df1)
      Value
Page       
1         1
2         1
3         1
```